# How to generate multiple qr codes in laravel

Tags: laravel, qr-code

I am working on a project in which i have to generate QR codes based on number of members in database. Each qrcode will have a unique string so i am generating a random string of 30 chracters. As of now i have 5000 members in database and i need to generate 5000 QR Codes.
When i run the application it fetches total number of records from database and in foreach loop i am generating QR Code, but the server responds to 503 error after 40-50 seconds though i set the limit in php ini setting for max execution time at 3600. below is the my code. I need advice on how can i achieve my goal what is best practice and how i can generate QR code in bulk with unique string and avoid duplicating qr code and store the qr image in storage folder as well its filename in database for later use to print it.

```
$data = \DB::connection('mysql2')->table('basicinfo')->where('is_approved','=','1')->whereIn('classOfMembership',$member_arr)->get(); //this return 4808 records

foreach($data as $d){
 $randomStr = Str::random(33);
 $image = QrCode::format('png')
   ->size(200)->errorCorrection('H')
   ->generate('https://example.com/'.$randomStr);
 $time_now = time();
 $output_file = '/qr-code/election-'.$request->election_year.'/img-' . $time_now . '.png';
 $image_name = 'img-' . $time_now . '.png';
 $insert_arr[] = [
   'election_year' => $request->election_year,
   'position' => $request->post,
   'qr_hash' => $randomStr,
   'qr_code_image' => $image_name
 ];
 Storage::disk('local')->put($output_file, $image); 
}
Ballot::insert($insert_arr);
```

Comment: 503 could indicate server is overloaded. Why not do this using queued jobs?

Comment: As @geertjanknapen has suggested, use a [queue](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues) to perform long running tasks in the background. You might also want to consider [chunking](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#chunking-results) your results.

Comment: how can i use qeueue or chunking can you guide me on it

Comment: The Laravel documentation is pretty thorough in providing both an explanation and examples of how to implement such things. Have a read of it and see how you get on.

Comment: Another idea would be to generate each image when requested via their URL, cache the result in your output files directory by unique ID.

Comment: Thankyou i will look into the documentation